# Where can I find google analytics ga id for report apis

Tags: android, google-analytics

For Google Analytics Real Time Data: get where can I find google analytics ga id for report APIs

Answer (score 0):

It is the **View ID**, you can find it in `View Settings` of the Administration panel in Google Analytics.